# req.user.populate(...) IS NOT A FUNCTION

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so this is my app.js
the thing i want to do is when go the cart in my website, show me all the products in the cart with the user model that i created which has a field of cart in that there is cart items, which has two fields one product id, and quantity.
so i want to populate the product id so i can see their inf on and ofcourse quantity in my cart.

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const errorController = require('./controllers/error');

const User = require('./models/user');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shop');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    User.findById('657167533934e81f519f9bbd')
    .then(user=>{
        req.user = user;
        next();
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
})

app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use(shopRoutes);

app.use(errorController.get404);

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://feri:Bardia2323@cluster0.acwxu0j.mongodb.net/shop?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
.then(result=>{
User.findOne().then(user =>{
    if(!user){
        const user = new User({
    name:'feri',
    email:'feriorse@gmail.com',
    cart:{
        items:[]
    }
});
user.save();
    }
});
    app.listen(3000);
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
})
```

and this is my shop controller. which i have a problem with the populate function.

```
exports.getCart = (req, res, next) => {
  req.user
    .populate('cart.items.productId')
    .execPopulate()
    .then(user => {
      const products = user.cart.items;
      console.log(products);
        res.render('shop/cart', {
          path: '/cart',
          pageTitle: 'Your Cart',
          products: products
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

and this is my user model.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name:{
    type: String,
    required:true
  },
  email:{
    type:String,
    required: true
  },
  cart:{
    items:[{productId:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Product',required:true},
    quantity:{type:Number,required:true}}]
  }
});
userSchema.methods.addToCart = function (product){
  const cartProductIndex = this.cart.items.findIndex(cp=>{
      return cp.productId.toString() === product._id.toString();
    });
    let newQuantity = 1;
    const updatedCartItems = [...this.cart.items];

    if(cartProductIndex>=0){
      newQuantity = this.cart.items[cartProductIndex].quantity + 1;
      updatedCartItems[cartProductIndex].quantity = newQuantity
    }
    else{
      updatedCartItems.push({productId:product._id,quantity:newQuantity})
    }
    const updatedCart = {items:updatedCartItems};
    this.cart = updatedCart;
    return this.save();
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

and this is my product model.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const productSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type:String,
    required: true
  },
  price:{
    type: Number,
    required:true
  },
  description:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  imageUrl:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  userId:{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'User',
    required:true,
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product',productSchema);
```

i tried updating the mongoose.
changing the name an all that.
i dont know what is wrong anymore.`your text`

Comment: I think you just need to keep in mind that [findById()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findById()) resolves with `null` if the document is not found

Comment: In your `exports.getCart` function what is `req.user` because you are chaining a `populate` to it. When you perform a `populate` it is done on the model, query or document returned by the query. It won't work on plain object. The `execPopulate()` function was removed in V6 too.

Comment: req.user its just one user that created in app.js if you see the code, and then i put it on the req

Comment: So if you `console.log('req.user=', req.user); console.log('req.user is', typeOf(user))` as the first statement inside the `exports.getCart` function what does it actually output in the console?

Comment: thanks jQueeny yeah it seems like when i delete the execPopulate , it works now. exec was removed as you said.